# how to set the permission to a user for stream publishing in facebook?

Tags: facebook, stream, publishing, permissions

I would like to post the stream from my website to facebook user wall by using facebook API..

1. I have created the facebook application
2. Posted the stream by application admin ..
   passed the parameter which required to this function..

   ```
   $this->facebook->api_client->stream_publish($comments,'From:blinkbee.com',$action_link,$f_user_id,$f_user_id);
   ```
3. Successfully posted the stream..
4. Then I changed the target_id and user_id of other users.. it showing the error like "USERID" does not resolve to a valid user ID..
5. I dont know how to set the permission to other users..

Please help me to solve it soon..
thanks
saran
http://careerjobz.com

Answer (score 0):

> 4.Then i changed the target_id and user_id of other users.. it showing
>   the error like "USERID" does not
>   resolve to a valid user ID..

This is because the USERID is either invalid or does not exist. You need to specify a valid USERID there, try to see what the USERID resolves it by echoing it.

For publishing stream for other users, you will need the **[offline access](http://blog.geehsien.com/2009/02/01/getting-offline-access-with-fbprompt-permission/)** from those users to be able to publish the stream.